# BASIC authentication in jersey JAX-RS service and Tomcat 6.0 getting failed

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am trying to do a BASIC Authentication in my service using Tomcat 6.0 and JAX-RS jersey implementation.

Below are the implementation steps I followed:

1) Added the Realm in **server.xml** like this:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" connectionName="XXX" connectionPassword="YYY" connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl" driverName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" roleNameCol="role_name" userCredCol="user_pass" userNameCol="user_name" userRoleTable="user_roles" userTable="users"/>
```

The same realm I am using in other JSP application, it is working fine over there.

2) Below is the **web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.infy.security</param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>      
  <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>BasicDemo</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>*</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <!-- <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint> -->
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <!-- The realm name is typically displayed by the browser in the login dialog box. -->
  <realm-name>Login</realm-name>      
</login-config>
```

Below is the service:

```
@Path("/authenticate")
@RolesAllowed({"Admin","Guest"})
public class BasicAuthenticationSecurity {

@GET
@Path("/wbiPing")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
@RolesAllowed("Admin")
public Response wbiPing(){

    System.out.println("Pinged!!!");
    return Response.ok("Pinged!!!").build();
}

}
```

After implementation, whatever is the input in the login authentication popup (even if the user is "Admin") I am getting the unauthentication error page. Below is the URL:

```
http://localhost:8002/BASICAuthentication/rest/authenticate/wbiping
```

Please let me know if I am misisng something.

thanks,

Comment: Have you traced that traffic using something like fiddler or charlese proxy?  That may help figure out what's going on.

Comment: Tried REST Console in chrome but not able to trace anything :(

Comment: Maybe try adding a method:  <http-method>GET</http-method>

Comment: tried that but of no use...other than the Realm, do I need to do some more changes in the server.xml? Any other hints?

Comment: I would look in your server.xml.  This all looks good.  I would send you ours, but we use ldap...

Comment: I had a look at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/secure.htm#BABGBJAC It seems that the method annotation `@RolesAllowed("Admin")` should be replaced by `@RolesAllows("Admin")`. But unfortunately I am not able to find anything like `@RolesAllows("ADMIN")`. Please let me know if I am missing some jars/API dependency in my application workspace. btw, I am using jersey implementation of JAX-RS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I wasn't able to get it running with the realm definition in the server.xml.

It started to work as soon as I moved the

```
<Realm
    className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
    driverName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.21.105.185:1552/CRODODEV.DE.MADM.NET"
    connectionName="1234556"
    connectionPassword="*****"
    userTable="cpim_users"
    userNameCol="user_name"
    userCredCol="password"
    userRoleTable="cpim_user_roles"
    roleNameCol="role_name"
    digest="sha-256" />
```

into the context.xml. The logging of the TomCat toled me that the server wasn't using the JDBC realm.