# Setting the Roles for @RolesAllowed in JAX-RS using jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I tried using `Basic Authentication` by changing the `server.xml` config of `Tomcat 6.0` but it did not worked: [BASIC authentication in jersey JAX-RS service and Tomcat 6.0 getting failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158554/basic-authentication-in-jersey-jax-rs-service-and-tomcat-6-0-getting-failed)

Hence I am opting a way where no server specific config is needed and I can add up the roles directly in my code (either client or server; not sure about theavailable options).

Please provide me some ideas about the possible options for setting the user roles so that I can authenticate my Web Service methods using the `@RolesAllowed` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go back and figure out why your security constraints weren't working. Maybe start with the default file realm before moving on to JDBC realms. @RolesAllowed in an annotation that triggers behavior in the container.

If you really want to do it yourself (a bad idea) they you'd probably start by creating a custom servlet filter that implemented the entire basic http challenge mechanism. Next you'd have to replace the SecurityContext provider in Jersey.

They "thing" that enables @RolesAllowed in jersey is this: http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/jersey-server/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory.java Which, by the way, don't forget to add as an init-param to your jersey servlet. The RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory gets its security info from an injected SecurityContext which I'm sure at some point just delegates off to the Servlet API for credential info.

So basically if you don't want to take the time to get security constraints working you are going to end up replacing most of the chain...like I said, a bad idea.

The features on application servers are there to keep you from having to spend time creating infrastructure code, if you write your own infrastructure code you're going to have a bad time.